# Run a stored procedure with parameters in stimulsoft report

Tags: sql-server, stimulsoft

I am trying to display a report that is generated by executing a stored procedure. The student table is defined as follows:

[image]

The stored procedure is defined in the database like this:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetStudentInfo]
    @StudentName NVARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT * 
    FROM Students 
    WHERE Students.Name = @StudentName
END
```

The data source has been defined accordingly, and a variable has been set to pass as an argument to the stored procedure.

```
EXEC GetStudentInfo @StudentName
```

However, it appears that the variable `StudentName` is not being properly passed to the stored procedure, causing it to not work correctly.

[image]

[image]

The preview tab:

[image]

And result in SQL Server profiler:

```
declare @p1 int
set @p1=12
exec sp_prepexec @p1 output,N'@StudentName varchar(50)',N'EXEC GetStudentInfo @StudentName

',@StudentName=NULL
select @p1
```

Comment: `EXEC GetStudentInfo @StudentName` maybe?

Comment: I did the same , it was just an example.

Comment: Profiler shows: ``@StudentName=NULL``.  I think,you do not  passed parameter to provider (command or query).

Comment: @ValNik Actually that is my problem ,I can not pass parameter to a Sp ,but I can pass them to a query in similar fashion.

Comment: Probably, you can not use named parameter in query. Try pass parameter @StudentName to query  and run query as ``SELECT * FROM Students  WHERE Students.Name = ?``  or  run stored proc as ``GetStudentInfo ?``

Comment: @ValNik  this `GetStudentInfo ?` doesn't work either .

Answer (score 0):

I was able to retrieve a report from a stored procedure using Stimulsoft by defining a select query and adding a variable to capture user input. Here's an example of how I achieved this:

```
USE [Student]
EXEC [dbo].[GetStudentInfo] @StudentName
```

In this case, @StudentName is the variable that captures the user input."